# Syntax error in importing .sql file to fresh database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, centos, virtual-machine

I have a perfectly working database and currently want to copy that to another server machine running CentOS7 VM. In the original server, I used phpMyAdmin to export .sql file for the database with "Quick setting" as shown below:

[image]

Then I uploaded the .sql file to the VM through FTP. Everything was still good until I ran the cmd `mysql -u root new_db < some.sql`. The error said:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2553295: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<br />

<b>Fatal error</b>:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in <b' at line 16
```

I'm 100% sure that the db worked without issues in the original server, and I haven't touched any source code in the .sql file. What may the `near <br />` warning suggest? Thanks a lot for any suggestions and help.

Comment: It looks to me like the export didn't complete and PHP has inserted an error message in your SQL file.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Yes the .sql file includes `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in <b>/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-4.9.5-all-languages/libraries/classes/Dbi/DbiMysqli.php</b> on line <b>609</b><br />` at the last line. And what do you mean by incomplete export? (Is the db too big or due to some other reasons). Should I use another export approach instead of phpMyAdmin build-in function? Thanks.

Comment: You used PHPMyAdmin to run the export, and PHP has stopped after five minutes, which is the default maximum execution time. You could edit `php.ini` to increase that and try the export again, but you'd be guessing at an appropriate value. Alternatively, use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) if you have access to the command line.

Comment: mysqldump works very well. Thanks a lot again for suggesting this approach!

Comment: Please share more details. Running `mysql` on the shell would never throw any PHP error messages. Also, how is this related to programming?